# Removing atexit tracebakc - atextit loops when it shouldn't

Tags: python, loops, raspberry-pi

How can I remove the trackback from the command output, and how can I stop this looping in the atexit function?

```
!/usr/bin/python

import time, atexit, sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    
#16 = Motor 1 - Forward
#18 = Motor 1 - Back
#11 = Motor 2 - Forward
#13 = Motor 2 - Back
#6  = Ground

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)

def exit_handler():
   GPIO.cleanup()
   print 'STOPPED'

while True:
   GPIO.output(11, True)
   GPIO.output(16, True)
    print "Forward"
    time.sleep(5)
    atexit.register(exit_handler)
```

It seems to work OK, and runs the motor controller on my Pi *(just - due to dodgy wiring [image: head]
)*

But when I run it, I get this as the output:

```
[wilf@Pi MovementCommands]$ 1/forward.py
Forward
Forward
Forward
Forward
Forward
Forward
Forward
Forward
Forward
Forward
Forward
Forward
Forward
Forward
Forward
Forward
Forward
Forward
Forward
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "1/forward.py", line 17, in <module>
    time.sleep(5)
KeyboardInterrupt
STOPPED
STOPPED
STOPPED
STOPPED
STOPPED
STOPPED
STOPPED
STOPPED
STOPPED
STOPPED
STOPPED
STOPPED
STOPPED
STOPPED
STOPPED
STOPPED
STOPPED
STOPPED
[wilf@Pi MovementCommands]$
```

For some reason it seems to be looping the exit_handler nearly as many times as the main bit loops - how can I stop it doing this - it can take ages to exit if it has be running for a while, as it loops the cleanup command. *(The main bit does not have to loop, but it is useful as visual indication that it is doing something - could I possibly just loop the `print` bit...)*.

I also seem to be unable to stop the traceback of `atexit` being displayed, without having to use `except KeyboardInterrupt`. This would be useful anyway, but I may later want to automate it by running it from a Bash script *(yes I could integrate it into it, but I don't want to)*.

Comment: Emoticons on StackOverflow? That's a novelty...

Comment: I had to add it as an image - I am a noob really, the only reason I have 100+ rep is my askubuntu account...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are re-registering the `atexit` handler *each time* your loop iterates. Python calls the function as many times as it has been registered.

Register the function just **once**. You don't need to call `sys.exit(0)` in your `atexit` function either, you are *already* exiting your program.

Corrected program:

```
import time, atexit
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

def exit_handler():
    GPIO.cleanup()
    print 'STOPPED'

atexit.register(exit_handler)

while True:
    GPIO.output(11, True)
    GPIO.output(16, True)
    print "Forward"
    time.sleep(5)
```

Alternatively, catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` and clean up in the exception handler:

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

try:
    while True:
        GPIO.output(11, True)
        GPIO.output(16, True)
        print "Forward"
        time.sleep(5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass  # silence the interrupt
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
    print 'STOPPED'
```

The `finally` block calls `GPIO.cleanup()` regardless of what exception occurred, the `except KeyboardInterrupt` just silences the keyboard interrupt exception.

Note that the traceback was never in the `atexit()` function, it is the reason the program is exiting and why `atexit()` is called at all. In other words, the exception preceeds the `atexit()` function call.

Comment: Wow, that's obvious *(now that it has been pointed out to me)* - but how do I get rid of the traceback?

Comment: The `KeyboardInterrupt` traceback you mean? Why not use `try:`, `except KeyboardInterrupt:` there? You can then also run your cleanup.

Comment: I don't want to use `KeyboardInterrupt` as then I don;t think a script could interrupt it. The atexit works fine, apart from the fault you pointed out, and the traceback.

Comment: The traceback only occurs because you are interrupting the program with `CTRL-C`. That is the keyboard interrupt.